# Requesting a new tag in SO

Tags: discussion

We are considering SO as one of the main channels for Q&A for SAP [cloud-s4sdk-pipeline-lib](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline-lib) which is aimed at providing reusable pipeline as a code library. Since this is a new topic and we cannot re use the existing tags, We would like to use **s4sdk** as the tag for the same. As you can see, I cannot create a new tag because of the technical limitation(reputations).

It would be really great if any of the community members help me to create a tag.

The same tag will be reused for:

- https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-examples
- https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline

Comment: Are there any questions that _should_ have this tag?

Comment: Yes, we will monitor this tag for all the Q&A related to s4sdk pipeline. We ask(promote the tag) community to use this tag while posting any question related to pipeline and library.

Comment: Okay, again, _"Are there any questions that should have this tag, **now**?"_ Are there any ___existing___ questions that are missing this tag?

Comment: Nope, currently there are no questions which should have this tag.

Comment: @RamKamath I'm curious, why is it needed then? Would it not make sense to create tags as and when they are needed?

Comment: Even if you want to create a new tag, there should be questions related to that tag. Starting a new tag and promising to ask questions doesn't seems to be a good idea.

Comment: @Script47 it helps in bringing all the question related to pipeline library in one place and avoid any redundancy. Also helps us to monitor if there are new questions by monitoring the tag.

Comment: @RamKamath but you mentioned that no questions currently exist that could use this tag therefore you'd be creating a redundant tag which is just as equally 'bad'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can't (shouldn't) create tags if there are no questions that can use the tag.

If someone asks a question about s4sdk, they are free to add `s4sdk` in the tags. This will automatically "create" said tag. (Provided they have [the privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) to do so)

Comment: on the second point of your answer. Unfortunately, one cannot add non exiting tag to his/her question.

Comment: @RamKamath: Yes, one _can_, as soon as that user [has 1500 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags). That's the way tags are created.

Comment: Okay, I was following a suggestion provided by SO while I was exploring how to organize our Q&A. It reads as follows                                     "creating new tags is a privilege; if you can't yet create a tag you need, then post this question without it, then ask the community to create it for you"

Comment: @RamKamath: _"then post this question without it,"_ < did you do that? You just said that there are currently _no_ questions that require that tag.

Comment: I will find question related to s4sdk pipeline and update this discussion. As of now I went through the proposed answer and I think I have some gaps in the information I have provided.