# Add a link to the tag creation FAQ in the 'How to Tag' guidance

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions

The 'How to Tag' guidance for creating new tags currently links to the front page of Meta. Is it possible to make it link to the [tag creation FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work) instead?

> [image: screenshot of the 'How to Tag' guidance]

That way, users will be better informed about the process, and as a result we can hopefully avoid situations like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358982/requesting-a-new-tag-in-so#comment529675_358984) (yeah, that user didn't post a question without the tag first, but they did follow the advice to post on Meta):

> Okay, I was following a suggestion provided by SO while I was exploring how to organize our Q&A. It reads as follows "creating new tags is a privilege; if you can't yet create a tag you need, then post this question without it, then ask the community to create it for you"